# Where is filechooser in javafx scene builder 2.0? I can't find it

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have java jdk 7.65, sdk 7.65. 
Where is filechooser in javafx scene builder 2.0? I can't find it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SceneBuilder is for building a Scene graph, i.e. for creating nodes and adding them to a root container that is intended to be added to a `Scene`.

`FileChooser` is not a `Node`; it cannot be placed in Scene graph; so it really wouldn't make sense to include it in SceneBuilder. The typical use of a `FileChooser` is that it's shown in response to the user action, such as pressing a button. This would be done in a handler method, not in the construction of the UI.

In other words, it's not really clear what you would do with a `FileChooser` if it were available in SceneBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

#### Where is filechooser in javafx?

The FileChooser class is located in the javafx.stage package.

---

#### File Chooser

> This chapter explains how to use the FileChooser class to enable users to navigate the file system. The samples provided in this chapter explain how to open one or several files, configure a file chooser dialog window, and save the application content.
>
> Unlike other user interface component classes, the FileChooser class does not belong to the javafx.scene.controls package. However, this class deserves to be mentioned in the JavaFX UI Controls tutorial, because it supports one of the typical GUI application functions: file system navigation.
>
> The FileChooser class is located in the javafx.stage package along with the other basic root graphical elements, such as Stage, Window, and Popup.

Source [Using JavaFX UI Controls](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm)